# How to make excel interpret Chinese characters in CSV file

Tags: excel, shell, csv, sendmail

I am sending a report from a unix shell script that contains chinese characters.

When I open the CSV report in plaintext editor like textmate I can see the chinese characters but when I open CSV report file in Excel I don't see the chinese characters, but some gibberish.

How do I "tell" excel that the file contains Chinese charset ?

Here is the code that sends mail and attaches the CSV file.

```
send_mail() {

v_mailpart="ZZ_/afg6432dfgkl.94531q"
echo "Mail to be sent to $RPT_SEND_TO"
echo "To: $RPT_SEND_TO
Subject: Blah Report as of $report_date_format;
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"$v_mailpart\"
MIME-Version: 1.0

This is a multi-part message in MIME format.
--$v_mailpart
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Disposition: inline

<html><body><p>Hi All,<p>Please find attached, the daily report <p>Thanks,
<br/>Blah Team</br/><br/><br/></p><p>NOTE: This is an auto-generated email. Do not reply to it. Please send an email to blah-group@mycompany.com in
 case of any issues.<p></body></html>

--$v_mailpart
Content-Transfer-Encoding:UTF-8;
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=\"UTF-8\";
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=blah-report.csv
`cat $spool_file5`" | /usr/sbin/sendmail -t
}
```

Comment: May I ask you how this posting is related to Excel? You are just creating an E-Mail, and as far I can see, you provide the proper `Content-Type`. Two things look odd to me: Can the `Content-Transfer-Encoding` really be UTF-8? I've never heard of it, and I would have used something like QUOTED-PRINTABLE. Also I would have expected to be an empty line after `Content-Disposition: attachment; ...`, but I'm not really a specialist when it comes to email, so I might be wrong here.

Comment: @user1934428 Well, the reason for this is because I am opening the CSV in excel and was wondering how to "tell excel" that the CSV file contains UTF-8 charset

Comment: Then I misunderstood the question (because you are also tagging it with the "shell" tag, and show code which relates embedding a text file into a mail header - which has nothing to do with controlling the encoding which is assumed by Excel). Maybe you could rewrite your  question accordingly, and also tag it with "excel" only.

Comment: I don't know much about Excel, and this is also a question, which is - as far I understood - **not** related to programming, so you would better ask it in a Microsoft Office forum. Since there is no 100%-rule, how a program can gess the encoding of a **text** file (which, after all, CSV is), I could imagine that Excel has somewhere an option, where the Excel user can explicitly set the encoding. There is however one thing you could try: Many programs assume UTF-8 implicitly, if the document starts with a BOM, so I would put a BOM at the start of your CSV file.

Answer (score 1):

It is AN encoding problem. A simple work around is open the file using google sheet and save as csv from google sheet.

The Windows Chinese OS use GBK as default Chinese encoding. You should download the Chinese for excel and set the encoding through the Option.

So you should encode it as GBK OR GB18130

- (1) Download Open Office (free and fast to install, have have higher
  file size than Cals in Ubuntu).
- (2) Detect your CSV encoding. Simply
  open your csv using Open office and choose an encoding method that
  display your Chinese character.
- (3) Save your csv to the correct
  encoding according to your operation system. Default Windows encoding
  is GBK for Chinese and Ubuntu is UTF8.